# How to use mock which is not passed to real object

Tags: c#, nunit

I have service `CarTankService` as shown below. It has `Add` method which i want to test. To be more detailed i would like to check whether `AddTank` `(inside Add)` will be reached.

```
public class CarTankService : ICarTankService
{
    private readonly ITankQuery _tankQuery;
    private readonly CarClient _carClient;

    public CarTankService(ITankQuery tankQuery)
    {
        _tankQuery = tankQuery;
        _carClient = new CarClient();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CarTank> GetTanks() => _carClient.Tanks;

    public void GenerateNewList() => _carClient.GenerateNewTanksList();

    public virtual void Add(CarTank tank)
    {
        if (_tankQuery.isExist(tank.Number)) throw new OwnException()

        _carClient.AddTank(tank);
    }

    public virtual void Remove(CarTank tank) => _carClient.RemoveCarTank(tank);
}
```

This is my test method class:

```
[TestFixture]
class CarTankServiceTests
{
    private Mock<ITankQuery> TankQuery { get; set; }
    private ICarTankService CarTankService { get; set; }
    private Mock<CarClient> CarClient { get; set; }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        TankQuery = new Mock<ITankQuery>();
        CarClient = new Mock<CarClient>();
        CarTankService = new CarTankService(TankQuery.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_NotExistReferenceNumber_AddTankReached()
    {
        TankQuery.Setup(uow => uow.isExist(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(false);

        CarTankService.Add(new CarTank());

        CarClient.Verify(uow => uow.AddTank(It.IsAny<ClientTank>()),Times.Once);
    }
}
```

`CarClient.Verify` for `AddTank` always show it was `0 occurence` in test, which in this case is not true. I am not sure but I think it's because `CarClient` model class because it's not injected directly insdie my service it always shows 0. AM i right? Is there any option to test it?

Comment: You need a way to either pass your mock of `CarClient` to the service, as it is it just creates a private one, or alternatively to be able to view the private instance of CarClient. Which one to do depends on your architecture and to some extent preferences - how much you should change your actual code in order to be able to test it.

Comment: @stuartd that's what i thought but i do not want to create interface for my model class "CarClient" just because i need to pass this object to my service. Is there any other way or is the way it has to be done? I think it would "not look correct" passing model object with interface ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mock your `CarClient` you have to setup all methods you want to use in your test (here `AddTank`). In you code we have two `CarClient` instances, one is mocked in your test and another is initialized in your constructor of `CarTankService`. So, you are calling the latter case while verifying the mocked one.

If you convert the `CarClient` to an interface and inject it, The solution is something like this:

```
[TestFixture]
class CarTankServiceTests
{
    private Mock<ITankQuery> TankQuery { get; set; }
    private ICarTankService CarTankService { get; set; }
    private Mock<CarClient> CarClient { get; set; }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        TankQuery = new Mock<ITankQuery>();
        CarClient = new Mock<CarClient>();
        CarTankService = new CarTankService(TankQuery.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_NotExistReferenceNumber_AddTankReached()
    {
        TankQuery.Setup(uow => uow.isExist(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(false);

        CarTankService.Add(new CarTank());

        CarClient.Setup(a=>a.AddTank(/*write you loginc*/));
        CarClient.Verify(uow => uow.AddTank(It.IsAny<ClientTank>()),Times.Once);
    }
}
```

**Here is more explanation:**

When you write `CarTankService = new CarTankService(TankQuery.Object);` in your test, it creates a new instance on your class (`_carClient = new CarClient();`), so the class has it's own instance, while the test class has it own too (`CarClient = new Mock<CarClient>();`) which is mocked. This line of code `CarTankService.Add(new CarTank());` adds the tank to the instance of class, while  in your test, you are verifying the instance of test class which has no tank (`CarClient.Verify(uow => uow.AddTank(It.IsAny<ClientTank>()),Times.Once);`).

Comment: And this is correct approach or its better to create sepqrate interface for carclient class model and inject into my servicd? I didnt do it because i read that i should not mock my model classes Just because for tests

Comment: It depends on your design pattern. I would prefer to create an interface for that.

Comment: using your approach causes to loss the control over your object here.

Comment: But is it really checks carclient's addtank call from cartankservice' add? I do not See how it corelates both objects. Can you explain?

Comment: I add some additional explanation to the post. I hope it whould be helpful.

Comment: I See but what to do, if i Just create interface for my model class   carclient Just because of test wouldn't be 'ugly' ? Normally i heard model classes resist in domain layer shouldn't have interface and be mocked. What you think?

Comment: Writing testable codes is not ugly. I think your goal to write this test is wrong(I would like to check whether `AddTank` (inside `Add`) will be reached)! If I were you I would write a test for `CarClient` class and check if it works properly, then write a test for `CarTankService` and check all the possible paths. However if you only want to pass your test, don't use a mocked `CarClient` object and change the out put type of `Add` function to return the number of tanks added. Then you can check the functionality of your method and make sure that it is working (or is reached).

Comment: I will also test my domain objects clases like CarClient as well later on but you mean you wouldn't check the reachability of AddTank inside CarTankService?

Comment: Yes, reaching to `AddTank` means it has to work properly and correspondingly `Add` has to be work properly. You should write your tests in such a way all possible paths be checked. I mean you have to make a circumstances in your test in which all code paths of your functions with all possible inputs are checked. So if your `Add` passed all the tests, you are sure that `AddTank` is reached and work properly. Then, focus on adding test cases and check all possible paths and inputs.

Comment: yes i agre, but hold on.. My test is exactly  one of the test paths, means to check if AddTank was reached therefore i should also test it.. and to do it i would need to build interface for domain model CarClient and inject it to properly test.

Comment: I think reach-ability is not the goal of unit testing! If it would, you had to check the reach-ability of each line of codes. That's impossible.

Comment: so why there is such thing like Verify then? Please of explanation

Comment: You have a unit called `Add`. If you think like TDD, I think it is better to change the `Add` out put to make sure it is work properly and make it testable (for example returns the number of tank added). Do you agree that if `Add` works properly it means that `AddTank` is reached and work properly?

Comment: ok but how could i rebuild my method Add then? For your information i use DDD. The service you see is Application layer service. it uses Query namespace to read therefore i ask query to see (isExist) and then inside CarClient there is a List of CarTank  which i add new item via AddTank (if its reached) of course. How could i rebuild it to test it properly. What could i return from the method or? Could you propose some change based on my example to better understand? Thank you !

Comment: Would it be for instance good to return from Add the _carClient.ClientTanks.Count or _carClient.ClientTanks ? That's what you ment?

Comment: Yes, this is an option. You can return 'True' or 'False' in `AddTank` and then return `_carClient.AddTank` in `Add`. Now, you can easily write test for `Add` and check reachability and functionality using assertion.

Comment: When then to make Reachability by Verify then if not in unit tests? Because from your inputs i understood that in unit test i should only check by returning value from method.

Comment: and if my method doesn't have anything to offer like my method Add which could return count of list to be reurned do you think returning true/fale is correct or maybe just check if not any exception thrown to verify method validation if method has anything to return?

Comment: I'm absolutely not a test expert and prefer not say any thing about this. It is better to research about it. About Nunit.Verify, I think it is designed to make you sure that how many times a function or method is called (think about recursive function that should be called a fix amount of times for a given input), so I think it's application is different from reach-ability (however we can use it to check the reach-ability).