# How to test method in unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have such `service` as below. Let's say i want to test `Create()` method. I read that in `unit testing` i should test by `comparing, counting` and so on. How could i then test my `Create()` method. Is it ugly to change return type from `void Create` to `bool Create` just to be able to check method output for testing purpose or that's not ideal idea? Can you propose something?

```
public class CreateCarService : ICreateCarService
{
    private readonly ICarQuery _carQuery;
    private readonly ICarRepository _carRepository;

    public CreateCarService(ICarQuery carQuery, ICarRepository carRepository)
    {
        _carQuery = carQuery;
        _carRepository = carRepository;
    }

    public void Create(Car car)
    {
        if (car == null) throw new CusException(Error, "Car object cannot be null");

        if (_carQuery.IsLoginExist(car.Login))
            throw new CusException(Error, "Message1");

        if (_carQuery.IsEmailExist(car.Email))
            throw new CusException(Error, "Message1");

        _carRepository.Add(car);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use mock for `carRepository` and check that it'll run `Add` method

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes, i know how to mock query and repository, but my question was more like how to test method whether it's working on not in general. From what I've read in unit tests methods could return something but in my case there is void. Should i not create void methods but for instance instead create bool return type to check method or?

Comment: Step back and ask yourself what you want to test here. You have this statement: `ccs.Create(someCar);` what does it mean for this method to have run successfully? What do you expect from it? If you were to be able to manually call this method, how would you afterwards verify that it did what it was supposed to? When you have these answers, you can then formalize those expectations and how to verify them into code.

Answer (score 4):

You might verify that for any valid `Car` instance `Add` method was called only once, by setting up the `Moq` behavior of `IsLoginExist` and `IsEmailExist` method an using a [`Verify`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification) method

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void CreateCarServiceTest()
    {
        var carQueryMock = new Mock<ICarQuery>();
        var carRepositoryMock = new Mock<ICarRepository>();
        var createCarService = new CreateCarService(carQueryMock.Object, carRepositoryMock.Object);

        carQueryMock.Setup(c => c.IsLoginExist(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
        carQueryMock.Setup(c => c.IsEmailExist(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);

        createCarService.Create(new Car());
        carRepositoryMock.Verify(c => c.Add(It.IsAny<Car>()), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

It also makes sense to check a negative cases, when `Create` method throws an exception

```cs
[Test]
public void CreateCarNegativeTest()
{
    var carQueryMock = new Mock<ICarQuery>();
    var carRepositoryMock = new Mock<ICarRepository>();
    var createCarService = new CreateCarService(carQueryMock.Object, carRepositoryMock.Object);

    Assert.Throws<CusException>(() => createCarService.Create(null));

    carQueryMock.Setup(c => c.IsLoginExist(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
    Assert.Throws<CusException>(() => createCarService.Create(new Car()));

    carQueryMock.Setup(c => c.IsLoginExist(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
    carQueryMock.Setup(c => c.IsEmailExist(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
    Assert.Throws<CusException>(() => createCarService.Create(new Car()));
}
```

You can split this method into different tests to have one `Assert` per test, or pass the parameters to it.

Comment: and this is crucial point, i've read that in unit test i should not check for instance whether some code line was reached (Verify) otherwise i would need to check many places in all methods. Isn;t better to have output from method and check comparing count or something? That would mean for example if i get expected count also Add was reached? Look at this post where i got conversation about that with @Alireza https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916220/how-to-use-mock-which-is-not-passed-to-real-object

Comment: @Arie IMO, it doesn't look as good idea. Your can check every case separately and in isolation from others, that's an essential goal of unit testing. Having the mixed output from different cases can cause some pitfalls with checking of output

Answer (score 1):

You want to test the "*expected behavior*" of the member under test. Since the member under test does not return any verifiable output and has a dependency on external abstractions, you should be able to monitor the interaction of the member under test with that external abstractions and verify the expected behavior

One such example

```
public void CreateCarService_Create_Should_Add_Car() {    
    //Arrange
    Car car = new Car {
        Login = "Login",
        Email = "Email"
    };

    ICarQuery carQuery = Mock.Of<ICarQuery>();
    ICarRepository carRepository = Mock.Of<ICarRepository>();

    ICreateCarService subject = new CreateCarService(carQuery, carRepository);

    //Act
    subject.Create(car);

    //Assert
    Mock.Get(carRepository).Verify(_ => _.Add(car), Times.Once);
}
```

The example above safely navigates through to the end of the member under test but lets say you wanted to test the exception is thrown for the null parameter case.

```
public void CreateCarService_Create_Should_Throw_CusException_For_Null_Car() {    
    //Arrange        
    ICreateCarService subject = new CreateCarService(null, null);

    //Act
    Action act = ()=> subject.Create(null);

    //Assert
    var ex = Assert.Throws<CusException>(act);        
}
```

You want to create tests for all the possible paths through the member under test. So take some time and review the subject under test and work out the possible test cases. Arrange the subject to satisfy those cases and exercise those cases to verify the expected behavior.

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the Moq mocking framework.

Comment: I agre checking Throw but Verifying if some line of code was reached seems to be useless otherwise for some method i would need to checked every line whether it was reached. Isn;t better to just check generally somehow the method like using some output count or whatever that would also be meaning if count is correct also Add was reached. This is exactly the point i had conversation with @Alireza: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916220/how-to-use-mock-which-is-not-passed-to-real-object

Comment: @Arie I am not checking that some line was reached. I am checking that the code behaves as expected in isolation given different inputs. If the subject under test provides no output to verify behavior then you have to check what the subject under test interacts with in order to verify expected behavior.

Comment: @Arie The provided answer above addresses the specific example given in your post. There may be different approaches depending on any given scenario. There is no one hard and fast way to do test things. That is way too broad of a topic and I am not about to debate what is considered useless or useful since that is open to opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change it to bool, just to test. A simple way you can do this is:

```
        [TestFixture]
        public class Test
        {
          CreateCarService createCarService;
          ICarRepository carRepositoryMock; 
        [Setup]
        public void InitializeTest()
        {
            var carQueryMock = new Mock<ICarQuery>();
            carRepositoryMock = new Mock<ICarRepository>();
            createCarService = new CreateCarService(carQueryMock.Object, carRepositoryMock.Object);
        }

        [Test]
        public void CreateCarShouldThrowIfNull() 
        { 
          //arrange
          Car car =null;

         //act and assert
         Assert.Throw<CustomException>(()=>
         {
            createCarService.CreateCar(car);
         });
        }
        [Test]
        public void CreateCarShouldThrowForInvalidLogin() 
        { 
          //arrange
          var car = new Car()
         {
            Login=null,
            Email="Email"
         };

         //act and assert
         Assert.Throw<CustomException>(()=>
         {
            createCarService.CreateCar(car);
         });
        }
```

And So on.

You can use `Assert.Throw` for invalid car objects or `Assert.DoesNotThrow` for valid car objects. Finally, you can test if the car was added to the repository by:

```
  [Test]
    public void CreateCarShouldAddCarToRepo() 
    { 
      //arrange
      var car = new Car()
     {
        Login="Login",
        Email="Email"
     };

     //act
        createCarService.CreateCar(car);

      var carRetrieved =carRepositoryMock.GetCar(car.id);//depending on your implementation
      //assert
      Assert.AreSame(car,carRetrieved);
    }
```